# How can I politely ask someone to call me? (As opposed to me calling them)

Tags: politeness, email, phone-calls

I recently contacted a restaurant where I had a bad experience, and a manager got back in contact with me. At the end of the email, they said:

> I would very much appreciate the opportunity to speak with you personally to address all of your concerns and regain your confidence in our ability to provide you with a great dining experience. Please feel free to contact me directly at (555)123-4567 or by email at name@example.com

I'm not really comfortable making phone calls, so I am sending an email response. But it just feels much less like "speaking with me directly" than a phone call. How can I politely inform the person that if they still want to talk, they can call me instead?

Comment: Why is this necessary?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai I'm... really not sure how to answer that question. It seems self-evident to me. I would like to let the person know that they'll need to call me, not the other way around.

Comment: Why do they need to call you? I don't understand why you can't call them.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai "I'm not really comfortable making phone calls"

Comment: @aaaaaa But that doesn't explain why they're comfortable receiving one. I can't really figure how to answer this question without knowing what's wrong with dialing rintaun dialing the phone themself.

Comment: I'm not really sure why the reason I don't want to make a phone call matters, but I suppose if I knew everything about this stuff, I wouldn't be asking a question. :) In short, making phone calls causes me anxiety. Receiving phone calls does not. I can appreciate that you might not understand that, but that's the reality.

Comment: @rintaun: Maybe you should look for answers how you get over your anxiety. That seems to be the real issue here.

Comment: I think most people would prefer that they chose when to call someone compared to being called whenever the other person has time for such a call. What the manager suggested (that you call him) is polite.

Comment: You're not alone. I totally understand your situation. My anxiety is maybe about something 'maybe the other person is busy or unavailable, what happens when someone else answers the phone, I don't want to bother them' ... stupid but that's the way my brain handles 'I have to call someone'.

Comment: @rintaun Well, we don't know it doesn't matter until you say why! That said, I've never interacted with someone who's anxiety went that way - usually it's anxiety about being on the phone at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just send an email that says something like:

> Hi,
>   I look forward to discussing this with you.  I am available Thursday
>   between 2 and 4pm.  Just give me a call, my phone
>   number is (xxx)xxx-xxxx.
>
> [your name here]

This does several things.

- It tells them that you are currently busy but approachable and that you actually want to have a dialog, as opposed to a "yell at them" session.  After all, if you just wanted to complain you could do that safely from the comfort of an email without fear of interruption.
- By giving a 2 hour window, it says that you value their time as well.  Hopefully this will help you come across as more reasonable because you aren't demanding that they drop whatever hot plate they have at that moment to speak to you.  I'm sure any restaurant manager would appreciate this and could easily find 10 minutes over the course of 2 hours to contact you.
- Finally, it does exactly what you want which is put the ball into their court to be the one that actually dials the phone.

Comment: Very good answer.  I'll propose a variant: "I am available Thursday between 2 and 4pm. Just give me a call at your convenience that afternoon.  If that afternoon doesn't work for your schedule, please let me know some other times that would work for you, or feel free to try my number at a random time.  My phone number is (xxx) xxx-xxxx."

Comment: @aparente001: I thought about adding something like that but the problem is that it invites another email from the restaurant manager proposing a different set of times and, potentially, for the manager to place the burden of dialing the phone back on the OP which is what we are trying to avoid.